# Change publishing rate in source code

Tags: c++

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm subscribing to `/camera/depth/image` topic, after some processing I want to publish it again but in different rate.

I'm already trying to do it using some code but I didn't succeed yet. (Publishing is working)

I found a very short answer that I'm trying to follow but not very clear enough. [Here](http://answers.ros.org/question/194418/change-publish-rate-of-a-topic/?answer=194429#post-id-194429)

EDIT - SOLUTION:

I found a solution in `throttle` package, but I don't get really exactly the rate I input which is g_period=`msgs_per_sec` in the package:

The rate I get is:

```
rostopic hz /depth_output 

average rate: 15.018
    min: 0.063s max: 0.069s std dev: 0.00187s window: 14
```

Here is it:

```
ros::Time g_last_time;
ros::Duration g_period;

g_period = ros::Duration(1.0/20); //msgs_per_sec

ros::Time now;
now = ros::Time::now();
if((now - g_last_time) > g_period)
 {
   depth_pub_.publish(depth_msg.toImageMsg());
   g_last_time = now;
 }
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/239734/change-publishing-rate-in-source-code/) by [ROSkinect](https://answers.ros.org/users/17876/roskinect/) on ROS Answers with karma: 751 on 2016-07-18

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You can use ros::Rate where frequency is the desired frequency.

```
// Run at the configured rate, discarding msgs if necessary

ros::Rate rate(frequency);

//main loop

while (ros::ok())
  {
  ros::spinOnce();
  rate.sleep();

  if (std::abs((rate.expectedCycleTime() - ros::Duration(1.0 / frequency)).toSec()) > 0.001)
  {
      // Change rate dynamically; if must be above 0, as 0 will provoke a segfault on next spinOnce
      ROS_DEBUG("Changing frequency from %.2f to %.2f", 1.0 / rate.expectedCycleTime().toSec(), frequency);
      rate = ros::Rate(frequency);
  }

}
```

---

Originally posted by [jeanpolochon](https://answers.ros.org/users/27330/jeanpolochon/) with karma: 140 on 2016-07-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1